# ffmpeg: thumbnail of frame, preserve aspect ratio, apply background / padding / fill colour

Tags: ffmpeg

I already have found out how to scale the thumbnail to stay within specified bounding dimensions while maintaining aspect ratio.  For example, to get the frame shown at 6 seconds into the input.mp4 video file, and scale it to fit into 96x60 (16:10 aspect ratio):

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 6 -vframes 1 -vf scale="'if(gt(a,16/10),96,-1)':'if(gt(a,16/10),-1,60)'" output.png`

This is fine, it works.

Next, I would like to do the same, but if the video's aspect ratio is not exactly 16:10, then I would like to force the output image to have an aspect ratio of 16:10 by taking the above transformation, and filling or padding the space with white.  That is, I want the output to be as if I took, say, a 96x48 image, and laid it over a 96x60 white background, resulting in white bars above and below the 96x48 image.

Ideally, I do not want to resort to using another tool or library, such as ImageMagick.  It would be best if ffmpeg could do this on its own.

Comment: The [pad video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) is worth investigating.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: If you submit an Answer with this content, I will vote it up and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I went with.  For the `-vf` argument:

`-vf "scale='if(gt(a,16/10),96,-1)':'if(gt(a,16/10),-1,60)', pad=w=96:h=60:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=white"`

This applies two filters in sequence, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
target_H = 2436
target_W = 1124

ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -ss 1 -vframes 1 -vf "scale=min(iw*2436/ih\,1124):min(2436\,ih*1124/iw),pad=1124:2436:(1124-iw)/2:(2436-ih)/2:green" output.png
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer my help to solve the issue.